# Fill parent div area when rotating img

Tags: css, reactjs

I've been trying hard to do the following:

In React I have a div with a fixed size, and inside of it I have an image.

I have 2 range sliders. 
One scales the image when dragged. 
The other rotates the image in a negative or positive direction.

Now this works fine. BUT when I rotate the image in either direction I would like the image to always fill the entire area of the parent div-container, as I eventually need to crop the image according to the parent div. Therefore I don't want any "empty" area(s). So the image needs to adjust its height (and width) so it always fills the area of the parent div WHEN I rotate.

The image is uploaded in react using DropZone and a call to a php file, then presented in the parent div.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Code below and a screen shot.

```
    <div style={{overflow: 'hidden', width:'280px', height:'200px', border: '1px dotted red'}} className='centered'>
                   <img src={imageFileHere} style={{ transform:'rotate('+this.state.rotateLevel+'deg) translate(-50%, -50%)', position: 'relative', top:'50%', left:'50%', width: 'calc(320px + '+ this.state.zoomLevel+'px)'}} alt='Setup'/>
                   </div>

                   Scale Image:<br />
                   <input onChange={(e) => {this._resizeImg(e)}} defaultValue='1' type='range' min='10' max='350' style={{width: '70%', maxWidth: '280px'}} /> Rotate Image:<br />
                   <input onChange={(e) => {this._checkRotateValue(e)}} defaultValue='0' type='range' min='-80' max='80' style={{width: '70%', maxWidth: '280px'}} />
</div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BWjx.png)

Comment: to fill these empty areas, aside rotate() you could also rescale it scale() , here is what i mean : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXzxVe

Comment: Hi. And Thanks for the advice. I did that to begin with but user also controls zoom in and out. So if rotating and scaling and then zoom out (image becomes smaller) it still needs to detect when empty areas emerge. Preventing further scale down.